# Image parallax is broken when opening new tab, on refresh it's fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css

When you open the website in a new tab then the `parallax` looks broken, but once you refresh the website it's fixed.

This is the simple html structure of the `image-section`

```
<div id="section3" class="section section-image parallax-window">
        <div class="trap-up-light"></div>
        <div class="container">
        </div>
        <div class="trap-down-light"></div>
    </div>
```

The `.trap-up-light` and `.trap-down-light` classes are two triangle masks to create the trapezoid effect. Everything worked just fine (see image below) but I wanted to add a parallax effect.

I'm using `parallax.js` which only needed this line of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.parallax-window').parallax({imageSrc: 'img/bg.jpg'})
});
```

So it adds my image to the `.parallax-window` class

You can watch it live [here](http://breakingnews.clouddesign.be/public/)

Working:
[image]

Broken:

[image]

Comment: It's not really fixed on refresh. When I scroll with the mouse, I can see ribbons of typewriter struggling above and underneath. But if I apply `#section2, #section4 { background-color: white }` it's gone.

Comment: That does indeed work, but my `.trap-up-light` isn't visible still (triangle above the div)

Comment: Uh yes, looks fine for me. I see exactly what the "Working" image shows above. Just apply a white background to sections #2 and #4. (Using Chrome)

Comment: I did, it's not "broken" anymore but on my screen the top is flat. If you want you can post your answer so I can mark it as "answered" as it helped me

Comment: Okay thanks, I did so, even though I regret my solution isn't really working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really fixed on refresh. When I scroll with the mouse, I can see ribbons of typewriter struggling above and underneath. But if I apply `#section2, #section4 { background-color: white }` it's gone. I see exactly what the "Working" image shows above.